# Nuxt 3: Difficulty Implementing useAsyncData for Data Fetching from contentful

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I recently migrated my project to Nuxt 3 and I'm attempting to utilize useAsyncData for data fetching. However, I'm encountering an issue where the async function doesn't seem to behave as expected.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
    const route = useRoute()
    const runtimeConfig = useRuntimeConfig();
    import { createClient } from 'contentful';

    const blogDetails = ref(null);

    const fetchData = async () => {
        const response = await client.getEntries({
            content_type: 'blog',
            'fields.slug': route.params.slug
        });

        return response.items.map(item => {
            let renderOptions = {
                renderNode: {
                    [BLOCKS.EMBEDDED_ENTRY]: (node, children) => {
                        if (node.data.target.sys.contentType.sys.id === "codeBlock") {
                            return `<pre>
                                <code>${node.data.target.fields.code}</code>
                            </pre>`;
                        }

                        if (node.data.target.sys.contentType.sys.id === "videoEmbed") {
                            return `<iframe
                                src='${node.data.target.fields.embedUrl}'
                                height='100%'
                                width='100%'
                                frameBorder='0'
                                scrolling='no'
                                title='${node.data.target.fields.title}'
                                allowFullScreen=true
                            />`;
                        }
                    },
                    [INLINES.HYPERLINK]: (node, next) => {
                        if (node.data.uri.includes("player.vimeo.com/video")) {
                            return `<div class="iframe-container">
                                <iframe
                                title="${next(node.content)}"
                                src="${node.data.uri}"
                                frameBorder='0'
                                allowFullScreen
                                ></iframe>
                            </div>`;
                        } else if (node.data.uri.includes("youtube.com/embed")) {
                            return `<div class="iframe-container">
                                <iframe
                                title="${next(node.content)}"
                                src="${node.data.uri}"
                                allow='accelerometer; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture'
                                frameBorder='0'
                                allowFullScreen
                                ></iframe>
                            </div>`;
                        } else {
                            return `<span class="color">
                            <a href="${node.data.uri}">${next(node.content)}</a>
                            </span>`;
                        }
                    },
                    [BLOCKS.EMBEDDED_ASSET]: (node, children) => {
                        return `<div class="content-img"><img
                            src="https:${node.data.target.fields.file.url}"
                            width='100%'
                            alt="${node.data.target.fields.description}"
                            /></div>`;
                    },
                },
            }

            const { id, createdAt } = item.sys;
            const { title, description } = item.fields;
            const featuredImage = item.fields.featuredImage.fields.file.url;
            const content = item.fields.details;
            const details = documentToHtmlString(content, renderOptions);
            const customDate = getCustomDate(createdAt);

            return {
                id, title, featuredImage, description, details, createdAt, customDate
            };
        });
    };

    const { data: blogDetails, pending, error, refresh } = useAsyncData('blogDetails', fetchData);
```

I've ensured the following:

The imports are correctly adjusted to point to their respective locations.
client.getEntries is accessible.
The relevant libraries are installed and imported correctly.
Despite this, the async function doesn't seem to fetch the data as anticipated.

Questions:

Is there anything I might be missing with the implementation of useAsyncData?
Does the structure of the fetchData function look correct in the context of Nuxt 3?

Comment: You have to set `await useAsyncData`. Maybe that solve the problem?